# Datatable assigning wrong values to string while calling

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have a `gridview`, in which there are multiple `columns` and `rows`.

While debugging it generates `datatable` as below

[image: Datatable]

While assigning values for first and second row in html table I call it like below

```
StrPriBody = StrPriBody + "<table style='width: 100%; height: 53px' border='1'><tr> " +
            "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolordet + " ;white-space:nowrap'><strong>Job Security </strong></td> " +
            "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolordet + "'>" + strgrid1 + "</td><br /> " +
        "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolordet + " ;white-space:nowrap'><strong>Opportunity for Promotion </strong></td> " +
            "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolordet + "'>" + strgrid1 + "</td></tr></table> ";
```

from the `datatable` code

```
foreach (DataRow row in dttable2.Rows)
    {
        /** Job security **/
        if (row["Rating1"].ToString() == "Y")
        {
            strgrid1 = "Poor";
        }
        if (row["Rating2"].ToString() == "Y")
        {
            strgrid1 = "Satisfactory";
        }
        if (row["Rating3"].ToString() == "Y")
        {
            strgrid1 = "Good";
        }
        if (row["Rating4"].ToString() == "Y")
        {
            strgrid1 = "Excellent";
        }
    }
```

but when I see the value for `strgrid1` it always comes as `Excellent`.  WHY ??

It is assigning wrong values. The screenshot of gridview is below. I want to see the correct values for those which are checked ones.

[image: GRID]

Kindly suggest why it is  taking wrong values

**UPDATE:**

Datatable code:-

```
DataTable dttable2 = new DataTable();
    dttable2 = CF.ExecuteDT("select cr.Mkey, cr.Rating1,cr.Rating2,cr.Rating3,cr.Rating4 from p_emp_Company_Rating cr  " +
                            "join p_emp_Exit_Interview ei on ei.Mkey=cr.Mkey where ei.mkey='" + HidMKey.Value + "'");
```

Comment: Are you assigning strgrid1 separately for each row or is that the only place you set strgrid1? If it's the latter, then strgrid1 will always end up being the result for last row in dttable2.

Comment: You need to show more "datatable " code, it is not yet clear where the problem is.

Comment: @pll33: No i am not assigning it separately. what to do for that  then ?

Comment: @user3185569: Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using one variable `strgrid1`  to build your entire table which has only one value when you're doing that, the last value.

You need to build your rows inside the loop:

```
StrPriBody = StrPriBody + "<table style='width: 100%; height: 53px' border='1'><tr> ";

List<string> titles = new List<string>()
{
    "Job Security", "Opportunity for Promotion" // etc..
};
Queue<string> titlesQueue = new Queue<string>(titles);

foreach (DataRow row in dttable2.Rows)
{
    string rowTitle = ""; // GET THE TITLE FROM SOME ARRAY OR LIST
    /** Job security **/
    if (row["Rating4"].ToString() == "Y")
    {
        strgrid1 = "Excellent";
    }
    else if (row["Rating3"].ToString() == "Y")
    {
        strgrid1 = "Good";
    }
    else if (row["Rating2"].ToString() == "Y")
    {
        strgrid1 = "Satisfactory";
    }

    else if (row["Rating1"].ToString() == "Y")
    {
        strgrid1 = "Poor";
    }      

    StrPriBody = StrPriBody +
        "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolordet + " ;white-space:nowrap'><strong>" + titlesQueue.Dequeue() + "</strong></td> " +
        "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolordet + "'>" + strgrid1 + "</td><br /> ";
}

StrPriBody += "<table/>";
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but how to get the `rowtitle` here, as anyway it will be hard code only.. if u know how to get in array let me know. thanks

Comment: and how do you know that this row in the dataTable if for this specific title ? Are the values for titles always in the same order in the datatable ?

Comment: yes they are in the same order in the datatable also.

Comment: Do you have the title as string in any column of the datatable ?

Comment: you mean to say `Ratiing1`, `Ratiing2` as string. ?

Comment: Check the answer now, you can store the titles in a list, array, or queue if you are sure of the order, and then access them in the loop.

Comment: Also, check if you need to change your if if pattern to if else depending on your business logic (in case you might have multiple Y on the same row or not). Also, consider store some ID as a foreign key for the title which can be in another table, or have it as enum in your Application. Storing the Strings as hard-coded and assuming a specific order is not a good practice IMHO.

Comment: yes, sure will take care of that. I am checking and I guess it may work perfectly. give me a moment and will let u know the status

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111185/discussion-between-coder-and-user3185569).

Comment: can u come on chat, need to discuss one small thing related to the issue.